# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar View time scale

Tags: 2010, calendar, outlook, limitations

Is there some way to adjust the time scale of Sharepoint Calendar Day View to make it show items with more than 30 min precision?

[Outlook Calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdwI.jpg) has a setting for that.
But in Sharepoint if you create a meeting which lasts from 10:00 to 10:15 the graphical representation of it is similar to the 10.00-10.30 meeting because of 30 minute scale. If you drag&drop your item the problem is the same: start and end time is adjusted by 30 minute 'steps':
[Sharepoint Calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfdDP.jpg)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but as far as I know it is not possible for the standard Sharepoint Calendard. You already have explained quite well calendar's behavior: In the calendar view you could only assing 30 minutes intervals, but in the event edit form you can change it to whatever you want.